# When Run As at Server,Eclipse - Tomcat - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletConfig

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm fighting the whole day with this:
I have DynamicWebProject. It worked fine. But at some point I desided to clean extra jar wich didn't used in project. After my cleaning, I've got a bunch of errors. So I rollback all my changes (I mean I retuned all jars back). But Also I played with Build Path of project, of Eclipse, of Debug config. Unfortunately I didn't remember this changes (with Path stuff). And when I run as at server, tomcat shows me this:

`

```
04.12.2012 16:37:43 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletConfig
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:103)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
04.12.2012 16:37:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /library threw load() exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletConfig
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:103)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
04.12.2012 16:37:43 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
04.12.2012 16:37:43 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
04.12.2012 16:37:43 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3556 ms
```

`

I'm real tied with this endless fight. What I'm doing wrong? What Eclipse and Tomcat tries to tell me?

---

**Done.**

So. How I restore functionality.
First of all, my project was backup in SVN repository.
Next I create new Workspace in Eclipse. new workspace in different folder. And Checkout project from SVN.
After that, at step - run at server, I caught errors, and added one by one missed libraries(jars). And whoa-la, it works!
So how I thought, problem resides in configuration of eclipce and project, also in Run/Debug Configuration. How to find errors in configuration, I don't know :( but I'll try at old workspace.

Comment: can you please post your servlet config file?

Comment: I don't realy use any myself servlets. I guess this servlet for axis2. I didn't change anything in it.

Comment: Do you check if all required jars are present in $CALINICA_HOME/lib ?

Comment: at this path all needed jars are present. I guess my problem lie within Eclipse configuration, project conf, or debug/run configuration..

Answer (score 8):

You are missing servlet-api.jar in your class path. Check it

UPDATED

```
1) Right click on project
2) Got to java build path
3) Click on add library in right hand side.
4) Choose server run time.
5) Click next and select your tom cat server.
6) Click on finish.
```

[image]

Then try again

Comment: Yep, in my searches i've found that this mistake could be with server-api.jar But where to write it? I'm using Eclipse. in DynWebProj, JavaResources->Libraries->ApacheTomcatv7.0 - servlet-api.jar - is present. When I'm trying to write this jar in "Debug Configurations.." I get more mistakes.

Comment: Nope. I've done this. But there is the same condition :( But maybe this gives some add.info  `INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [718] milliseconds.
2012-12-04 17:29:10,067 [WARN ][host-startStop-1][.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet] - Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
04.12.2012 17:29:10 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletConfig`

Comment: Check your WEB-INF/lib folder have this jar if not add it manually and re try whether this helps to you.

Comment: checked. axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar in WEB-INF/lib. Also i added it to debug/run configuration. and the error stack has changed to this `    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
    04.12.2012 17:43:33 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet AxisAdminServlet as unavailable
    04.12.2012 17:43:33 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /library threw load() exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Java Build Path`, go to `Libraries`, click on `Add Library`, choose `Server Runtime`, click `Next`, choose your webserver and click Finish. Clean and deploy to see if it works.

Comment: Yep, i've done it like in the prevoius answer. And also clean project, clean tomcat work directory. the problem not gone. Maybe i doubled some jar?

Comment: You can use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `t` and type javax.servlet.ServletConfig to see if you have added any duplicate jars. Just keep this runtime library and remove any other library/jar which provided this class and try once.

Comment: I like this hotkey combination. But it shows (javax.servlet.ServletConfig) only once. So I don't know if it doubled some where.

Comment: In this case, there is no chance for a duplicate jar being added. Could you check if the `axis` jars are there of different versions?